# How does Realm try to allocate more than the device capacity?

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm, out-of-memory

I'm trying to better understand the behavior and conditions that may cause abnormal increase in Realm file, so the questions that I ask are directed more towards the general Realm behavior.

To provide a little context, we use Fabric for crash reporting, and we notice there are crashes related to Realm, with the message:

```
Fatal Exception: RLMException
mmap() failed: Cannot allocate memory size:2684354560 offset:0
```

This is happening on iPhone 7 with iOS 11.2.2 (15C202). The device has [2GB RAM capacity](https://www.gsmarena.com/apple_iphone_7-8064.php), and Realm tried to allocate 2.68GB, which is obviously rejected by the operating system.

#### I'm aware that:

- There's a lot of Github issues similar to this memory allocation problem, and I've read most (if not all) of them.
- This is likely a "version pinning" issue, where there's too many old "snapshots" of data kept in the disk therefore caused the increase in .realm file size.
- There might be something wrong in how we use Realm (e.g. not wrapping calls of Realm-related objects that may retain `RLMRealm`) and we need to fix it.
- We should perform Realm file compaction on startup to make sure the Realm file size does not inflate, but this doesn't work for users already experiencing this crash because compaction needs to map current Realm file.
- (Edit: forgot to add this point) In background threads, we should wrap Realm instances (and its usage) within autoreleasepool to prevent version pinning.

#### Questions:

1. Imagine I have a 200MB Realm file. If I tried to initialize `RLMRealm` on 3 different threads (without doing reads/writes), will each Realm instance call mmap to allocate 200MB (totaling in 600MB of RAM usage)?
2. Related to question 1, does it make any difference if I didn't do read or writes vs. simultaneously reading (no writes) vs. mix of read and writes?
3. When Realm tries to allocate 2.68GB of memory, does that mean the Realm file size is also 2.68GB?
4. If the 2.68GB file size is caused by writes in previous session, how can Realm possibly contain 2.68GB worth of memory in previous session? Or is there any behavior that I'm missing here?

Comment: The short answer is "wrapping Realm instance on the async global dispatch queue with autoreleasepool"

Comment: @EpicPandaForce: Sorry, I forgot to add this. I'm aware of wrapping Realm in autoreleasepool, but I see this as a solution/preventative steps. I'm trying to understand the events that cause the Realm file to be inflated. Thanks for the comment!